# solaris + egrep command syntax not work

Tags: unix, shell-script, grep, solaris

my target is to match snmpmanager string from /etc/hosts file in Solaris machine

I don’t get any match output from the following command (but snmpmanager already defined in host file) why??

```
 egrep -i '(^|[[:space:]])snmpmanager($|[[:space:]])'  /etc/hosts
```

my host file

```
 10.170.10.5      loghost
 10.170.10.61   Master SyslogSer vip Tcc NtpServer1 NtpServer2 snmpManager snmpManagerPA1 snmpManagerPA2
```

I also tried the following but without success -:(

```
   egrep -i '(^|[\s])snmpmanager($|\s])'  /etc/hosts
   egrep -i '(^|[\t])snmpmanager($|\t])'  /etc/hosts
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Solaris' regular expression parsing is limited at what it can do.

You can try doing:

```
egrep '(^| )snmpmanager($| )' /etc/hosts
```

But I would simply use PERL and `\b` tags.

Comment: I find the solution for solaris its -  grep -iwc snmpManager (only need to add w flag)

Comment: @eytan if your solution works, its good to have you make it an answer, and accept it, so the question is closed out